# Sylius2 Install Database Error

Tags: php, database, symfony, installation

I'm trying to install Sylius. I already create the project with: composer create-project -s dev sylius/sylius.
But when im try to do the setup with: php app/console sylius:install 
I get this error of nesting leves max reached:

> Success! Your system can run Sylius properly.
>
> Step 2 of 4. Setting up the database.
>
> Creating Sylius database for environment dev.  It appears that your
>   database already exists.  Would you like to reset it: y
>
> 3/6 [|||||||||||||||             ]  50%
>
> Fatal Error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,
>   aborting! EB\K8\Sitio Web\Actual\Nueva
>   carpeta\k8malabares\vendor\symfony\symfony\
>   ony\Component\Routing\Matcher\Dumper\DumperCollection.php on line 81

I already turn off xdebug and change max_input_nesting_level to 1000 and xdebug.max_nesting_level to 1000 by the way.

Could you give others solutions?

---

#### Solved

I was working with the wrong php.ini
I was editing     \Program Files\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini
instead of    \Program Files\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the max_input_nesting_level - it hasn't come into action. Can you confirm you've restarted Apache / Nginx and also php-fpm.

Make sure also that max_input_nesting_level isn't defined anywhere else in your php.ini